# How to Sort and Group using MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a following table

```
-----------------------------------
Date        |      Prefilling  |  Ref
-----------------------------------
10/10/2017  |       5          |  dinesh
17/10/2017  |       8          |  Ajay  
07/05/2017  |       5          |  Aarthi
01/01/2018  |       8          |  Kumar 
-----------------------------------
```

How to perform order by and group by in same time?
I am using following query but its not giving actual result

```
  SELECT * FROM (  
        select * from table order by str_to_date(date,'%d/%m/%Y') DESC  
    ) AS tmp_table group by  Prefilling
```

and i am expecting the result, along with Ref

```
Array 
(
  [5] =>  10/10/2017, dinesh
  [8]  => 01/01/2018,  kumar
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering why you're storing dates as strings, when it'd be easier to query storing data from mysql's built-in date functions. It's not to late to change your design if you're not too far into this.

Comment: @Bill you've a gold on php, why not close it if you think it's a possible duplicate? Edit: ;-)

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I sometimes hesitate to close questions, if there's any slim possibility that they are not an exact duplicate. But you're right, in this case it's a classic greatest-n-per-group question. There are hundreds of those answered already.

Comment: @Bill and an interesting description it is for that tag; good choice.

Answer (score 1):

Based from the result you've showed, you wanted to get the latest date for each `Prefilling`. You can so this by using `MAX()` and order it using the largest value.

```
SELECT  Prefilling, MAX(STR_TO_DATE(`date`,'%d/%m/%Y')) AS MAX_DATE
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY Prefilling
ORDER   BY MAX_DATE
```

Here's a [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a65be1/2)

Below is the updated answer based from your updated question. You can separately retrieve the latest date for each `Prefilling` inside a subquery and join the result with the original table itself provided that it matches on both conditions - Prefilling and latest date to get all the columns.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    TableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  Prefilling, MAX(str_to_date(date,'%d/%m/%Y')) AS MAX_DATE
            FROM     TableName
            GROUP   BY Prefilling
        ) b ON a.Prefilling = b.Prefilling
                AND str_to_date(a.date,'%d/%m/%Y') = b.MAX_DATE
ORDER   BY b.MAX_DATE
```

And a [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aede03/2)

Comment: Soory @John Woo, I am expecting the output along with Ref.

Comment: @Thirukumaran see my updated answer.

Comment: @Thirukumaran what you mean by *expecting the output along with Ref*??